# Loading a collada file with Vertex Colors using three.js

Tags: colors, three.js, vertex, collada

I'm trying to load a dae file using three.js, but I can't get the material to show. I can't find any examples that use a dae file to load vertex colors that are in the file itself. I can get it to load at threejs.org/editor by setting the material to MeshBasicMaterial and the property Vertex Colors to Vertex Colors. I tried to replicate that in code but I don't think I quite understand how. Here is my loader function...

```
loader.load( 'objects/chair.dae', function ( collada ) {
//dummy1.dae
    var dae = collada.scene;
    var skin = collada.skins[ 0 ];
    console.log(collada.scene);
    //collada.dae.materials[0] =   collada.scene.children[0].children[0].material;
    //dae.material = collada.scene.children[0].children[0].material;
    //var material = collada.scene.children[0].children[0].material;
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
    });
    collada.scene.position.set(0,0,0);//x,z,y- if you think in blender     dimensions ;)
    collada.scene.scale.set(15.0, 15.0, 15.0);
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(collada, material);
    scene.add(mesh);
    //scene.add(collada.scene);
    var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper(50);
    axes.position = dae.position;
    scene.add(axes);
    var gridXZ = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 10);
    gridXZ.setColors( new THREE.Color(0x8f8f8f), new THREE.Color(0x8f8f8f) );
    gridXZ.position.set(0,0,0 );
    scene.add(gridXZ);
});
```

This is producing an error.

Comment: Here is the dae file I'm trying to load... https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ghvsq3uqaehsex/chair.dae?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

As for the code, basically you have to change the material of the mesh in the Collada object. Something like:

```
        loader.load(
            // resource URL
            'models/example.dae',
            // Function when resource is loaded
            function ( collada ) {
                var dae = collada.scene;

                // CORRECT FOR IMPORTER
                // collada object with only vertex color are not correctly loaded
                dae.traverse( function(child) {
                    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                        child.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: true } );
                    }
                });

                dae.position.set(0,0,0);
                dae.scale.set(10, 10, 10);

                scene.add(dae);
                animate();
            },
            // Function called when download progresses
            function ( xhr ) {
                console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
            }
        );
```